# How to set anti-forgery cookie domain at run-time?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core-2.1

Suppose I have an ASP.NET Core app hosted at `admin.xyz.com` and I need to set the anti-forgery cookie for `*.xyz.com`. I'm currently configuring the anti-forgery services like:

```
services.AddAntiforgery(opts =>
{
    opts.HeaderName = ANTIFORGERY_HEADER_NAME;
    opts.Cookie.Name = ANTIFORGERY_COOKIE_NAME;
});
```

I can statically set the domain this way `opts.Cookie.Domain = "xyz.com"` but I'm looking for a way to do it at run-time, something like:

```
Domain = string.Join('.', Request.Host.Host.Split('.').Skip(1));
```

Or in a place where I have access to the `HttpContext` object. I thought of a middle-ware but I think it's too much complicated.

Do you know a simple way to do this? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could replace the [`CookieBuilder`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.http.cookiebuilder?view=aspnetcore-3.1) inside the [`AntiforgeryOptions`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.antiforgery.antiforgeryoptions.cookie?view=aspnetcore-3.1) and provide your own [`Build`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.http.cookiebuilder.build?view=aspnetcore-3.1) implementation that set the domain value explicitly.

Something like this:

```
public class CurrentDomainCookieBuilder : CookieBuilder
{
    public override CookieOptions Build(HttpContext context, DateTimeOffset expiresFrom)
    {
        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(Domain))
            Domain = string.Join('.', context.Request.Host.Host.Split('.').Skip(1));

        return base.Build(context, expiresFrom);
    }
}
```

And then when configuring Antiforgery, use the new builder:

```
services.AddAntiforgery(options =>
{
    options.Cookie = new CurrentDomainCookieBuilder
    {
        // default configuration for Antiforgery cookies
        SameSite = SameSiteMode.Strict,
        HttpOnly = true,
        IsEssential = true,
        SecurePolicy = CookieSecurePolicy.None,
    };
});
```